# Why im getting DocumentBuilder parse exception?

Tags: java

im getting an exception when the code is trying to cast the document. This is a code that i've found in internet, so if somebody can explain me how this code works, more exactly how the DocumentBuilder that im using works. Thanks to everyone

This is the code:

```
private static Document getDocument(String nombreArchivo) throws Exception 
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(nombreArchivo);
        return doc;
    }
```

Here is the link to the complete code:

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/xpath-attribute-evaluate/

Comment: How are we supposed to know where you got that code from and what it does? We at least need to know from which libraries or packages those classes come (unless they are yours).

Comment: Check the stacktrace, it'll probably tell you all you need to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this code works. I try this code. This below code, I try to execute.

- exception `trying to cast the document`

  Import should be `org.w3c.dom.Document` for this document.
- It will through `runtime error` if the file not exist or the file is not a valid `xml` file.

  So, ensure valid `xml` file exist in the location.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
...
...
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //keep hello.xml file in project root directory
    Document d = getDocument("hello.xml");
}
    
private static Document getDocument(String nombreArchivo) throws Exception 
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(nombreArchivo);
    return doc;
}
```